# PHP Datatype mismatch on comparison

Tags: php, operators, mismatch

So I have 2 variables, `var1,` `var2`.

```
$var1 = "53,000,000" //- integer
$var2 = 10 //- string
```

In the end I want to compare both, so I

```
$var1 = (int)str_replace(",","",$var1); // => 53000000 - integer
```

Here's my issue .. if I do:

```
if($var1 > $var2)  
    $var2 = $var1
```

I get `$var2 = 0` .... Why ?
.. running on PHP 5.2.14

**EDIT** Accidentally typed in substr_replace instead of str_replace. Updated.

Comment: what does $var2 = 10 - string mean?

Comment: I suggest you to read the [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). E.g. you don't need `<br>` for a line break, just put two spaces at the end of the line...

Comment: @Felix, thanks for the tip  
@ Mark - should be clear now with Felixs` edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a couple semicolons, but here's the code:

```
$var1 = "53,000,000"; //- integer
$var2 = 10; //- string
//In the end I want to compare both, so I

$var1 = (int)str_replace(",","",$var1); // => 53000000 - integer
//Here's my issue .. if I do:

if($var1 > $var2)  
    $var2 = $var1;

var_dump($var1, $var2);
```

And here's my output:

> int(53000000) int(53000000)

I used 5.2.6, but it shouldn't matter.  Do you have any other code in between what you're showing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()` instead of `substr_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the wrong parameters for substr_replace, so $var1 is evaluated to 0. I guess you wanted to use str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

No need for type casting. just do the str_replace

Here is code

```
$var1 = "53,000,000" ;    
$var2 = 10;  
$var1=str_replace(',','',$var1);  
if($var1 > $var2)    
    $var2 = $var1;

    echo $var2;
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, that's why I posted here. Normally it should

Comment: I tried Ravindrans code and it worked with PHP 5.2.4. Did you try this on a blank php-script? Are you sure there is no interference with other code?